# MySQL - creating a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help, I want to create a query and is difficult for me, how can I create a query to sort table A by value and if the values are equal to check in table B by which value are higher between value1 and value 2?

As example first 2 rows from table A have the same value, so if we compare with table B the order should be 2,1 because in table B 5>3

table A

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 6 |

table B

| id1 | id2 | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 1 | 3 | 5 | 2 |

Comment: It won't work. Your ordering heuristic lacks "stability". That means the algorithm could run in circular references. In simple terms, your secondary table could eventually say that row #1 goes after row #2, row #2 after row #3, and row #3 after row #1. What would you do then? This design is faulty.

Comment: @TheImpaler  in the table A will not be more than two values equals

Comment: This data really needs to be normalised otherwise you are going to be deep down a rabbit hole.